# components button sets state of main class react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a TouchableOpacity Button in my react-native component (Grid) and I need to change the state of the class where I'm calling the component (App.js). Is this possible?

App.js

```
import Grid from '../components/Grid'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
      opt: '1'
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Grid/>
      </View>
    );
  };
}
```

Grid.js

```
export default class Grid extends React.Component {
  _setMainState = () => {
    this.setState({
      opt:'2'
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._displayList}>
            <Text>Set App.js State</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a state setter to your child component, although it's not considered a best practice, as it might cause an infinite re-renders loop.
Try using context, or wrap your element in another element that stores this value.

```js
import Grid from '../components/Grid'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      opt: '1'
    };
  }
  
  changeOpt(newOpt) {
    this.setState({
      opt: newOpt,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container} changeOpt={this.changeOpt.bind(this)}>
        <Grid/>
      </View>
    );
  };
}
```